# How do I make a 320x480 ImageView fill the entire emulator screen (320x480 mdpi in size)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I'm working with an emulator screen set at 320x480 MDPI. I created a background image in fireworks with the exact size of 320x480 pixels, placed it in the drawable MDPI folder, and set it as an `ImageView` in hopes it would fill the entire background of the emulator. *The problem* is the background only fills vertically, but seems to leave empty space equally on the left and right horizontally.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you don't just setBackground on your root view?

Either way, filling the background in Android is a troublesome business. I suggest reading this question: [Handling different screen resolutions for background images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634929/handling-different-screen-resolutions-for-background-images-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height ="fill_parent" 
           android:scaleType="fillXY" />
```

Note that this will cause it to scale in the X direction to fill the space, which will slightly distort the image.

Answer (score 0):

please don't use a `ImageView`, just set the `android:background` property of the root layout in your xml. Look at this example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_image_here" >
    .....
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps you. Best Regards

Comment: If the app has multiple backgrounds will this still work? Thanks a ton!

Comment: What do you mean? you want to change dynamically your background image?

Comment: My app has more than 1 background depending on the activity. For example the homescreen has a background, and the store has a different background.

Comment: Ok, if you have an xml layout for each activity, you can define the image that you are going to put in background with no problems. If you want to change the background dynamically by code, you must use the setBackgroundDrawable(your_drawable) method of the layout. BestRegards

Comment: Hi, if the answer was util for you, please remember to accept it. BestRegards!

Comment: I''ll test this on monday. Thanks!