# image is strectching on the mutiple devices on Android phones

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm developing the android app to display image banner when you open the app on android mobile.

The problem is, image banner is stretching on different android devices based on the resolution of the phone. This resulted, image-banner get too much stretched.

How to get Responsive image banner on Android app?

Comment: I think you need to have multiple images of different resolutions, all specified correclty in the manifest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634929/handling-different-screen-resolutions-for-background-images-in-android

Comment: post your image view xml code

Answer (score 0):

Take different size images in different `drawable` folders in res  folder with same name.

There is a 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio in `drawable` size by `DPI`.

```
LDPI - 0.75x   
MDPI - Original size  
HDPI - 1.5x  
XHDPI - 2.0x  
XXHDPI - 3x  
XXXHDPI - 4.0x   
   ​
```

For example if a `100x100` image is a baseline `(MDPI)`,

```
LDPI - 75x75 
HDPI - 150x150       
XHDPI - 200x200  
XXHDPI - 300x300  
XXXHDPI - 400x400
```

and so on.